# ElasticSearch query for field with given value or no value

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for a way to query my documents to find all document that matches these conditions:

1. Either the property `eye.keyword=RIGHT`
2. Or the property `eye.keyword` is not defined (the value is missing/null)

This is my query, but I'm not sure if it's right and it's written in the most efficient way. I don't need score on these results:

```
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "terms": {
          "eye.keyword": [
            "RIGHT"
          ],
          "boost": 1
        }
      }
    ],
    "filter": [
      {
        "terms": {
          "indexLocation.keyword": [
            "global",
            "mycompany"
          ],
          "boost": 1
        }
      }
    ],
    "must_not": [
      {
        "exists": {
          "field": "eye.keyword",
          "boost": 1
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative": true,
    "boost": 1
  }
}
```

This is an example of document:

```
{
  "_index": "ophthalmiclens",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "GLOBAL_SP015_0300603412_IT",
  "_version": 3,
  "_score": 1.6931472,
  "_routing": "global",
  "_source": {
    "gradientColor": false,
    "indexLocation": "global",
    "salesPrice": 39.423,
    "description": "MyBrand Addpower 60 1,5 Ø 65 Sph 2,5 Cyl 0 Add 0,75 Dx",
    "range": false,
    "diameterMin": 65,
    "additionMin": 0.75,
    "preset": true,
    "purchasePrice": 8.9,
    "source": "STOCK",
    "type": "DEGRESSIVE",
    "trial": false,
    "manufacturer": "MyBrand",
    "sphereMax": 2.5,
    "lineCode": "ADDPOWER-65",
    "multiCoating": false,
    "cylinderMax": 0,
    "design": "SPHERIC",
    "imageUrl": null,
    "diameterMax": 65,
    "solidColor": false,
    "hardCoating": false,
    "mirroring": false,
    "sku": "0300603412",
    "thumbUrl": null,
    "barcode": "0300603412",
    "prismMax": null,
    "sphereMin": 2.5,
    "coatingCode": "",
    "lineDescription": "Addpower 60",
    "cylinderMin": 0,
    "index": 1.5,
    "photochromic": false,
    "discontinued": false,
    "searchKey": "GLOBAL_SP015_0300603412_IT",
    "prismMin": null,
    "eye": "RIGHT",
    "taxRate": 4,
    "material": "ORGANIC",
    "additionMax": 0.75,
    "polarized": false
  }
}
```

Comment: post a (or couple) sample document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any query inside filter block will not be considered for scoring. This is also called filter context. So everything should be inside filter block. The query structure should be as below

```
query
  |_ filter
        |_ location = {a, b}
        |_ should
              |_ eye = right
              |_ eye = null (or eye missing)
```

The query translates as :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "indexLocation.keyword": [
              "global",
              "mycompany"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "eye.keyword": [
                    "RIGHT"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "eye"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```